# Hard color transition gradients

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am trying to reproduce this hard transition of colors with the gradient tool.

I had this  gradient:

[image]

And what I need  was  hard transition between of the colors like here -

[image]

What is the trick to achieve this hard stop?

Comment: I realize this is a *very* old question.... the *trick* is the *order* in which color stops are added. Add the preceding color stop first, then add the new color stop after it.. i.e. first blue stop - then second blue stop - then first green stop - then second green stop - then first red stop - etc.... If you mix up *when* the stops are added, it's possible two stops **won't** stack properly when they are at the same location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the location field. 
Make two points the same value. That way there is no transition between points.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add an additional colour stop. In your second screenshot, the right stop is actually two at exactly the same spot.

You will achieve a hard transition if you use these:

- stop 1 at 0%: dark blue
- stop 2 at 10%: dark blue
- stop 3 at 10%: light blue
- stop 4 at 100%: light blue

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to create a slight blend between the colors.
Red at 0%, Red at 18%
Purple at 20%, Purple at 38%
Yellow at 40%, Yellow at 58%
Green at 60%, Green at 78%
Blue at 80%, Blue at 100%
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the other answer doesn't work for me (in the most recent version of Ai) I am blocked from moving the "location" enough to make the transition a "hard" one. this worked.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to use a live paint object.  I achieved the hard stops I needed by using lines to cut through a shape and just fill the sliced areas with the colors you need.[image]

Comment: This creates multiple objects though. With a gradient you only need **one** object. This also, doesn't *really* answer the question. The question was about gradient functionality, not how to achieve the appearance with other methods.

Comment: I agree with you, Scott. Hard color stops don't exist in Illustrator, but they do in Cinema 4D, and I find them very convenient there. I was just offering a workaround, if the person who asked the question is willing to have multiple objects. The live paint object itself is like a sublayer, so if I select and move that, it behaves as if it's one object.